# addClass removeClass not working in IE..!

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, addclass

jQuery functions addClass and removeClass do not work properly when I use them to change the appearance of a div tag in Internet Exploer (IE). However, they work fine in other browsers.

Here is sample code to illustrate my problem:

```
if ($('#tdh').hasClass('current')){
    $("#u50").addClass('u59c');
    $("#u59").addClass('u59b');
    $("#u61").removeClass('u59b');
}
```

CSS:

```css
.u59b {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Segoe UI Light;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 13%;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 196px;
}

.u59c {
    color: #3B5998;
    font-family: Segoe UI Light;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 10%;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

HTML

```
            <a href="Page/tdh.aspx" id="tdh" class="current">
            <div id="u59" class="u59 u124-pad">
               Title1
            </div>
            </a>
            <a href="Page/tdh2.aspx" id="tdh2">
            <div id="u63" class="u59 u59b u124-pad">
                Title2
            </div>
            </a>
```

Comment: Show your HTML markup

Comment: `addClass` and `removeClass` work. Something else is not working.

Comment: define "doesn't work". Are the classes not attached, or they merely have no effect?

Comment: I highly doubt you've found a bug in `addClass`, more likely your logic is wrong and so your expected result != actual result.

Comment: This only work in IE 10.

Comment: In this case that condition will not be executed because the #tdh does not have the .current class

Comment: @Vleran: the .current class will be add when page load by another script and it work well... i used the debug (F12) and the .current class already added but the state of menu not change.

Comment: Than make sure you are executing this script after the one that adds tha .current class od try running the script that adds and remove classes inside an $(window).bind("load", function(){ ... your code for the load event ... });

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
if ($('#tdh').hasClass('current')){
    $("#u50").attr('class','u59c');
    $("#u59").attr('class','u59b');
    $("#u61").removeAttr('class');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />` inside the head tag
or this `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge;chrome=1">`

Make sure you are executing the script that adds and removes the classes after the one that adds tha .current class or try running the script that adds and remove classes inside an `$(window).bind("load", function(){ ... your code for the load event ... });`

Answer (score 0):

con ExtJs: class: 'xxx-readonly', se supone que ya tiene esta clase el input, es necesario poner otra vez el foco (senderField.focus(true, 12)), para IE, y para los otros navegadores, esto no da problemas.

--Edit in english--

> with ExtJs : class: 'xxx - readonly ' is supposed to already have the input this kind , it is necessary to focus ( senderField.focus (true , 12) ) , for IE, and other browsers again, this does not It gives problems .

```
field.addListener('focus', function(senderField){
    this.readOnly = this.el.dom.readOnly = false;
    this.getActionEl().removeClass('xxx-readonly');
    senderField.focus(true, 12);
});
```

Comment: Please use English on this website.